# Can not override Super hotkey

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, workspaces

I binded `Super+A` `Super+S` `Super+Z` and `Super+X` keys to switch among 1-4 workspaces. `Super+Z` and `Super+X` work as expected, but `Super+A` launches search applications, just `Super` launches search and `Super+S` launches workspace switcher. How can I get rid of binded search action on `Super` key?
Unity Tweak Tool doesn't have such settings, in system settings there is no even action with binded `Super` key.

OS:Ubuntu 13.04
Laptop:Lenovo Thinkpad